# LSTM BPTT with wide input?

Tags: lstm, backpropagation

I was following Tensorflow's own time [series/LSTM tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series), and there's something I don't quite understand about the whole process around Backpropagation Through Time (BPTT).

The resources I've found explain how prediction for a time in a future with an offset work (the "`offset`" in the tutorial, and the `t+3`rd time instance in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time))

What I don't understand is how does this generalize to where the input width is more than 1?

So in the Wikipedia article we see the case for `inputWidth=1`, `outputWidth=1` and `offset=3`.

I think I understand if `outputWidth>1` then you'd just start using not only the last, but also previous cell predictions as output. I also understand if `offset>1` the you just unroll the network into offset number of steps (as shown on Wikipedia).

But what if `inputWidth>1`? Let's say `inputWidth=k (k>1`)!

In this case, do you unroll the same RNN multiple times in parallel, and somehow average the weights? Do you unroll the same RNN `k` times sequentially? What does that look like?

Comment: What do you mean with "width"? Do you mean "length"?

Comment: @ncasas yeah, basically with how many timesteps you pass as input. Check the linked resources, should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unroll the same RNN multiple times, but not in parallel. The RNN needs both an input and the previous step, therefore, you unroll the same RNN for the first time step, then for the second, and so on.

For each step it is always the same RNN, so the weights are the same each time:

[image]

Comment: I think what this image shows is just showing `inputWidth=1`, `outputWidth=5` and `offset=5`. You're taking `x_t1`, `x_t2`, `x_t3`, `x_t4` and `x_t5` (in red), putting it through the RNN (light blue) with shared weights and predict  `y_t1`, `y_t2`, `y_t3`, `y_t4` and `y_t5` (in dark blue). I'm interested in how it works when you can use `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, (`inputWidth=3`)(!!) with an offset of let's say 2and maybe `outputWidth=1`. So the input is  `x_t1` & `x_t2`, (with y_t3 as the label) `x_t2`& `x_t3` (with y_t4 as the label), and `x_t3` &`x_t4` (with y_t5 as the label).

Comment: You are giving too much importance to `inputWidth`, `outputWidth` and `offset`, but the   RNN always works the same regardless of them. These parameters are specific to that tutorial and are only meant to define input and output data in that very case. Your `inputWidth` is just the length of the input, and therefore it is also for how many time steps the output of the RNN is ignored. `outputWidth` is just for how many timesteps you zero-out the input once the input has been consumed.

Comment: Note that an LSTM can be used in many ways, not only the way you suggest. It is possible to have the LSTM ingest inputs and, at each timestep $t$ (starting from $t=0$) make the output be the prediction for $t+1$. It is possible to have the RNN ingest many input timesteps and after that, have it predict a single value, or multiple values (zero'ing out the input for those timesteps).